Swift asynchronous sequence missing updates from @Published property
I’m encountering an issue in my app where a test occasionally fails. I’ve managed to narrow the problem down to this code snippet. The snippet contains two asynchronous sequences that both observe and modify the same @Published property, fire.
My expectation is that the asynchronous sequences will receive all updates from the @Published property, ensuring the test always succeeds. However, after a certain number of test runs (around < 100,000), the test hangs and never completes.
At first, I suspected a data race issue, but the problem persists even after annotating the class with @MainActor, to ensure that the whole class runs on the same thread.
On successful tests the console prints:
createStream1(): true
createStream2(): true
createStream1(): false

On unsuccessful tests the console prints:
createStream1(): true
createStream2(): true
createStream1(): true

The Code snippet:
final class Tests: XCTestCase {
    @MainActor func test_SUTStream1() async {
        await SUT().toTest()
    }
}

@MainActor
class SUT {
    @Published private(set) var fire = false

    init() {}

    func toTest() async {
        let cancelable = Task {
            await createStream2()
        }
        await createStream1()
        cancelable.cancel()
    }

    private func createStream1() async {
        fire = true

        for await didFire in $fire.values {
            print("\(#function): \(didFire)")
            if didFire == false {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func createStream2() async {
        for await didFire in $fire.values {
            print("\(#function): \(didFire)")
            if didFire == true {
                fire = false
                break
            }
        }
    }
}


What is the cause for this problem? Why will the asynchronous sequence sometimes miss the update from the @Published property?
How can this problem be fixed?


There are two issues:

The problem is that values does not buffer its values in the presence of back-pressure. So, if subsequent values are published before an existing one has been consumed, the previous value will be dropped.

And even when isolating these to the same actor, there is a race between the continuations. As SE-0306 – Actors warns us (emphasis from original):

Implementation note: At an implementation level, the messages are partial tasks (described by the Structured Concurrency proposal) for the asynchronous call, and each actor instance contains its own serial executor (also in the Structured Concurrency proposal). The default serial executor is responsible for running the partial tasks one-at-a-time. This is conceptually similar to a serial DispatchQueue, but with an important difference: tasks awaiting an actor are not guaranteed to be run in the same order they originally awaited that actor. Swift’s runtime system aims to avoid priority inversions whenever possible, using techniques like priority escalation. Thus, the runtime system considers a task’s priority when selecting the next task to run on the actor from its queue. This is in contrast with a serial DispatchQueue, which are strictly first-in-first-out. In addition, Swift’s actor runtime uses a lighter-weight queue implementation than Dispatch to take full advantage of Swift’s async functions.

So, in general, tasks (and continuations) of the same priority tend to run FIFO, but not strictly so: You may occasionally see partial tasks not honor FIFO order.


The combination of these two factors mean that you may occasionally drop values.

To focus on the first point, consider the following, in which I have added delays (to mitigate the race of my second point). This will consistently manifest the behavior:
@MainActor
class Foo {
    @Published private(set) var value = 0

    init() {}

    func experiment() async throws {
        let publishTask = Task {
            for i in 0 ..< 10 {
                value = i
                try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(300))
            }
        }
        
        let consumeTask = Task {
            for await value in $value.values {
                print(value)
                if value == 9 { break }
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
            }
        }
        
        try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try await publishTask.value
            try await consumeTask.value
        } onCancel: { 
            publishTask.cancel()
            consumeTask.cancel()
        }
        
        print("done")
    }
}

Calling experiment, that will produce:
0
6
9

If you do not want it to drop values, you can add a buffer to the consumeTask:
let consumeTask = Task {
    let sequence = $value
        .buffer(size: 10, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropOldest)
        .values

    for await value in sequence {
        print(value)
        if value == 9 { break }
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
    }
}

That will capture all the values (up to the buffer size, of course).
There are other patterns that one can employ to support different back-pressure behaviors, but hopefully this illustrates the fundamental issue.

Thank you so much! I always thought that the async stream automatically buffers the values.
This indeed seems to have solved the problem. The test does not fail anymore.
But one thing still leaves me wondering. How would you explain the output:
"createStream1(): true
createStream2(): true
createStream1(): true"?
Why does createStream1 updates twice with the value "true"?
I would understand it, if createStream1 only updates once and fails to update on the "false" value, as it does not buffer it currently.

I agree that publishing true twice defies expectations. In your example, you set the published property it to true and then set it a second time back to false. Those are the only values that should be published. I suspect it is a manifestation of some race which simply is not handled well by AsyncPublisher and/or the published property wrapper. We generally don’t create two AsyncPublisher for a single observed property, so it’s probably not an edge case that they contemplated. Feel free to post a bug with Apple.

Thank you so much. This cost me two days trying to figure out why I was losing messages coming from a Bluetooth peripheral. I was converting an Publisher into an AsyncStream and it was losing messages due to the lack of buffering. The agony.
